# Minimize your URLs in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, router, remap

I want my site work as:
`example.com/$key router to:`example.com/home/search/$key`

and

`example.com/search/$key router to:`example.com/home/search/$key`

What do I do? Please help me.

Ps:home is controller, search is method of home
I use my version 2. of codeigniter
$key is variable

Comment: `$key->direct` what's this ? Explain more!! unclear

Comment: Hello @PHUONG NT can you give us a real example? For example: example.com/1234 should lead to: example.com/home/search/1234 ?